# WPS process chaining

Tags: geoserver, wps

I am getting an error when I try to chain a GeoServer WPS subprocess in a `gs:UnionFeatureCollection` process.

```
<wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>gs:UnionFeatureCollection</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>first</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wps" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS">
            <ows:Identifier>gs:Query</ows:Identifier>
            <wps:DataInputs>
              <wps:Input>
                <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
                <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
                  <wps:Body>
                    <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2" xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp">
                      <wfs:Query typeName="topp:states"/>
                    </wfs:GetFeature>
                  </wps:Body>
                </wps:Reference>
              </wps:Input>
              <wps:Input>
                <ows:Identifier>filter</ows:Identifier>
                <wps:Data>
                  <wps:ComplexData mimeType="text/plain; subtype=cql"><![CDATA[contains("wkb_geometry",'POINT(-96.41 35.50)')]]></wps:ComplexData>
                </wps:Data>
              </wps:Input>
            </wps:DataInputs>
            <wps:ResponseForm>
              <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="application/json">
                <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
              </wps:RawDataOutput>
            </wps:ResponseForm>
          </wps:Execute>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>second</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
<wps:ComplexData mimeType="application/json"><![CDATA[{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[...]}]]></wps:ComplexData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
  </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="application/json">
      <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

If I run this request (with some JSON in the CDATA block) I get a NullPointerException:

```
2016-04-13 14:29:53,393 INFO [geoserver.wps] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2016-04-13 14:29:53,509 ERROR [wps.executor] - Process execution failed
org.geotools.process.ProcessException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geotools.process.factory.AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory$InvokeMethodProcess.execute(AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory.java:565)
    at org.geoserver.wps.executor.ProcessStartupFilter$ProcessStartupWrapper.execute(ProcessStartupFilter.java:51)
    at org.geoserver.wps.executor.DefaultProcessManager$ProcessCallable.call(DefaultProcessManager.java:201)
    at org.geoserver.wps.executor.DefaultProcessManager$ProcessCallable.call(DefaultProcessManager.java:169)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geotools.process.vector.UnionFeatureCollection.execute(UnionFeatureCollection.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.geotools.process.factory.AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory$InvokeMethodProcess.execute(AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory.java:549)
    ... 7 more
2016-04-13 14:29:53,513 INFO [geoserver.wps] - 
Request: execute
    service = WPS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:4080/geoserver/
    identifier:
        value = gs:UnionFeatureCollection
    dataInputs:
        input[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@1bdca30 (value: first, codeSpace: null)
            reference = net.opengis.wps10.impl.InputReferenceTypeImpl@ea11c1 (body: net.opengis.wps10.impl.ExecuteTypeImpl@15f7579 (language: null, service: WPS, version: 1.0.0, baseUrl: null, extendedProperties: {}), encoding: null, href: http://geoserver/wps, method: POST, mimeType: text/xml, schema: null)input[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@1358603 (value: second, codeSpace: null)
            data = net.opengis.wps10.impl.DataTypeImpl@da231f
    responseForm:
        rawDataOutput:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@ac5ddc (value: result, codeSpace: null)
            mimeType = application/json
```

If I run the subprocess and paste the output of that into the input block then I get the correct answer back.

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that currently there is a [bug](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOT/issues/GEOT-5403) in GeoTools that causes this issue when unioning filtered collections.

I have committed a [fix](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/pull/1171) into the master branch and will hopefully backport it to 14.x later this week.